# Why isn't my dependency listed in my manifest.mf?

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have an EJB project that requires org.apache.commons.lang3. I have in my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.kable.newsstand.kdsejb</groupId>
<artifactId>kds-ejb</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.kable.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>kable-super-pom</artifactId>
    <version>[0.1,1.0)</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    ....
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>ejbModule</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>ejbModule</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Dependencies>org.apache.commons.lang3</Dependencies>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

When I Project > Export > EJB Jar File, the dependency isn't listed in the MANIFEST.MF

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: BRay
Build-Jdk: 9.0.1
Created-By: Maven Integration for Eclipse

I have included the maven-ejb-plugin
I also included the archive -> manifestEntries -> dependencies nodes for the plug-in

Comment: Please show your full pom file...furthermore run on command line via `mvn clean package` instead from Eclipse...

Comment: Updated with most of the pom.xml. I cut out most of the dependencies to trim length.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, @khmarbaise 's response, lead me to look at some stuff and my results are as follows.

Change the maven-ejb-plugin configuration in the pom.xml as follows.

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <jarName>kdsSession</jarName> <!-- I need a different jar name -->
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}</outputDirectory> <!-- I want my jar in the root, not the /target -->
                <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Dependencies>org.apache.commons.lang3</Dependencies>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Then I created a new Run Configuration "Run as maven build..." with ejb:ejb for the goal.

I use the new Runtime configuration to build the ejb.jar instead of the Export -> EJB Jar.